# array / looping through numbers to get_post_meta

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, loops

I have post meta in WordPress that stores slide_image1 - 9, and slide_text1-9 and slide_embed1-9.

I want to be able to loop through all the possibilities, and store the meta values (if there are any) and then check if they are empty to decide if a slide should be displayed. Basically, we want to say, check for any data for that slide#, and if there is a value, then display a slide.

Here is what I have right now:

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 10; $i++) {
$slide_image . $i = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'slide_image'.$i, true);
$slide_embed . $i = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'slide_embed'.$i, true);
$slide_text . $i = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'slide_text'.$i, true);
if ($slide_image.$i !=='' || $slide_embed.$i !=='' || $slide_text.$i !==''){
echo 'there is a thing for this'
}}
```

This is obviously not working - i am assuming i need to use an array, but I can't figure it out- can anyone help please??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$slides = [];

for ($i = 1; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $slides[$i]['image'] = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'slide_image'.$i, true);
    $slides[$i]['embed'] = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'slide_embed'.$i, true);
    $slides[$i]['text'] = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'slide_text'.$i, true);

    if ($slides[$i]['image'] !=='' || $slides[$i]['embed'] !=='' || $slides[$i]['text'] !=='') {
        echo 'there is a thing for this'
    }
}
```

It's not quite clear from your question whether you want to display a slide if it has all of the attributes, or if it has any of them.  The code you have is saying, "If I have any data available, show slide" rather than, "If I have all data available, show slide".

Comment: Thanks @watcher ! I did want it to fire if ANY of them had content, so it's working great.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define `$side_image` and the following as array:

```
$slide_image = []; // or $slide_image = array();
$slide_embed = [];
$slide_text = [];
```

Now you can use it in your for loop like this:

```
$slide_image[$i] = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'slide_image'.$i, true);
```